# Pulsar producer send_async() with callback function acknowledging the sent message

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar, python-pulsar

I have a use case where messages from an input_topic gets consumed and sent to a list of topics. I'm using `producers[i].send_async(msg, callback=callback)`  where `callback = lambda res, msg: consumer.acknowledge(msg)`. In this case, consumer is subscribed to the `input_topic`. I checked the backlog of `input_topic` and it has not decreased at all.  Would appreciate if you could point out how to deal with this? What would be the best alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the output of your pulsar-admin topic stats command? Specifically, I am interested in how many subscriptions are on the topic and what the relative producer vs. consumer rates are, i.e., are messages getting published faster than your consumer can process them?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the `consumer.acknowledge(msg)` has actually been called? One possibility is the producer cannot write messages to the topic, and if the producer with infinite send timeout, you will never get the callback.